# Passbook pass not working in iOS7 - only works in iOS6

Tags: ios, ios7, passbook

My passbook passes are currently working in iOS6 and not iOS7.

I've replicated the problem in the iOS simulator. The console log from the iOS7 simulator gives me this:

```
Nov 13 14:10:10 XXXX.local backboardd[779] <Error>: __hid_dispatch_pthread_root_queue_create_block_invoke: specific=0x4d530d0 pthread_self=0xb0115000 
Nov 13 14:10:10 XXXX.local backboardd[779] <Error>:__hid_dispatch_pthread_root_queue_create_block_invoke: specific=0x4d52f10 pthread_self=0xb0197000 
Nov 13 14:10:18 XXXX.local MobileSafari[818] <Warning>: Invalid data error reading pass pass.xxxxxxx.xxx.xx.ticket/[barcode]. The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified. 
Nov 13 14:10:18 XXXX.local MobileSafari[818] <Warning>: PassBook Pass download failed: The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid.
```

I don't think it's the  lines as I've checked the team identifier and pass type identifier and they both match what's in the dev center.

So I think this must mean something:

```
__hid_dispatch_pthread_root_queue_create_block_invoke
```

Any ideas?

The error message displayed on the screen is "Download Failed - safari cannot download the file", but I think thats just a standard message.

Comment: Sounds like this could be a problem with the signature not containing a signing date. This was not enforced in iOS6 but is in iOS7. If you can post a link to a .pkpass bundle, I can have a quick look. It would also help if you could mention how you are signing your passes (your own code or a 3rd party library).

Comment: Also, the backboard daemon errors are very unlikely to be related. Your pass errors are being generated by MobileSafari.  Try turning on additional Passbook logging from the developer menu on an iPhone or iPod and you should be able to see exactly what `passd` (the Passbook daemon) doesn't like about your signature.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Here's a test pass that doesn't work for me: http://www.filedropper.com/passtest I'm doing the signing in dotNet and using my own code (which is based on an early version of this code: https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/dotnet-passbook).

Comment: How do I turn on additional passbook logging? I'm testing in the xcode iOS simulator, by the way.

Comment: You can only turn on logging on a device, it does not work in the simulator.  I have had a look at your pass and it fails on iOS6 and iOS7 - can you double check that your certificate is not expired or revoked.

Comment: @PassKit thanks for the help! So it looks like the iOS6 simulator was not worried about the expired certificate but the iOS7 simulator was! So when i loaded them up on actual devices I saw the error across the board. I had originally ruled out the possibility of a certificate error, because I'd assumed if that was the case, I'd be seeing it consistently. If you'd like to add an answer, to the effect of "Check your certificates" I'd be happy to make it as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having looked at your pass and the signature, everything seems to match therefore this points to a problem with your certificate. Is it possible that your certificate is expired or has been revoked?

Comment: Thanks @PassKit. It had expired. It's worth noting that my ios6 simulator had no problem with my expired certificate, and the ios7 simulator did.

Comment: @PassKit, thanks for commenting on this. I'm having the same issue as Ev. I looked at my certificates they are still valid. I've also went through the signature process and I believe I've got that correct as well, but clearly I'm still doing something incorrectly since Safari on my ios 7 phone does not recognize a pkpass file. Can you help me figure out where I've gone wrong? I've got a test file at http://scottallenlewis.com/harvest-kids/. If you put any number in and submit it should generate a very simple pass for you. Thanks in advance for your help.